# Does reflection in $y=x$, preserve maxima/minima for $z=f(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know if given a function that is symmetric in $ x=y $ ,  i.e.
\begin{align*}
  f(x,y)=f(y,x),
\end{align*}
is the following true
\begin{align*}
  (a,b) \min \; \iff  (b,a) \min \\ 
  (a,b) \max \; \iff  (b,a) \max
\end{align*}
? I geomerically speaking, I am sure that

\begin{align*}
  (a,b) \;\text{is one of min or max} \iff  (b,a) \;\text{is one of min or max} \\ 
\end{align*}
is true, but the above proposition is much stronger.

**What I have tried:**    I tried using the hessian and the signature of the matrix, however, I wasn't able to progress far. I tried using eigenvalues, but I get stuck and I get back to the hessian where eigenvalues don't seem to be the key as I can't see an appropriate change of basis.

I am not sure if this proposition is even correct, I would appreciate if anybody can shine some light on this.

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t understand what you’re asking. Did you leave some things out?

Comment: @bubba apologies, I had a LaTEX error. Is the question clear now?

Comment: @MathsWizzard $\,(a,b)\,$ is a maximum iff $\,f(x,y) \le f(a,b)\,$ over some domain $\,\forall (x,y) \in D\,$. Since $\,f(a,b)=f(b,a)\,$ it follows that $\,f(x,y) \le f(b,a)\,$ so $\,(b,a)\,$ is also a maximum by definition. The only required assumption is that the domain $\,D\,$ be symmetric in $\,(x,y)\,$ i.e. $\,(x,y) \in D \iff (y,x) \in D\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Swapping $(x,y)$ accompanies swapping $( a,b)$ point.i.e, the new point has new $(x,z)$ or $ (y,z) $ coordinates.